# Unable to add items to Roblox Table

Tags: arrays, null, roblox

I am having difficulty troubleshooting some code.

I have a for loop and in it I clone a part (called EnemySiteHub).

I expect that I can store each cloned part to a table (called EnemySiteTable).

Unfortunately, even though the loop runs successfully and I actually see the cloned EnemySiteHubs during a run of the game.. **The table is size remains 0.**
Trying to access the table in code gives a nil error.

Code snip:

```
  local ENEMYSITE_COUNT = 5
    local EnemySiteTable = {} -- [[ Store the table of enemy site objects ]]
    
        -- Loops until there are the amount of enemy site hubs set in ENEMYSITE_COUNT
            for i = 1, ENEMYSITE_COUNT do
                
                --Makes a copy of EnemySiteHub
                local enemySite = ServerStorage.EnemySites.EnemySiteHub:Clone()
                enemySite.Parent = workspace.EnemySites
                
                EnemySiteTable[i] = enemySite
```

This line of code causes causes the error below.

```
local enemySiteTableSize = #enemySiteTable
```

18:12:37.984 - ServerScriptService.MoveEnemyToSite:15: attempt to get length of a nil value

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`#array` is used to retrieve the length of arrays. You will have to use some sort of `table.function()` or use a `for i,v in pairs(EnemySiteTable)` loop.

Here's some more information: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Table

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Would you discourage using EnemySiteTable[i] = enemySite ?  Is it unreliable to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pyknight202

The problem originated somewhere else in my code.

The EnemySiteTable is in a module script.

This code below is the correct code to give access to the EnemySiteTable

```
--Have the table of enemies accessible 
EnemySiteManager.EnemySiteTable = EnemySiteTable
```

I had an error (typo) in that line of code.
The effect of that error kept returning a nil table, giving a table size of 0.